# How to get diff between tow queries in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, studio3t

I have collection

```
[{ 
    "_id" : "5c9a69ef42c82b0197a2ffb8", 
    "key" : "a",  
    "language" : "en", 
    "version" : "0.1", 
},
{ 
    "_id" : "5c9a69ef42c82b0197a2ffb8", 
    "key" : "b",  
    "language" : "en", 
    "version" : "0.1", 
},
{ 
    "_id" : "5c9a69ef42c82b0197a2ffb8", 
    "key" : "b",  
    "language" : "en", 
    "version" : "0.2", 
},
{ 
    "_id" : "5c9a69ef42c82b0197a2ffb8", 
    "key" : "c",  
    "language" : "en", 
    "version" : "0.2", 
}]
```

so I have 2 queries that getting version 0.1 and version 0.2,
And I need to find the difference between them?

I need to get all of translation 0.2 that does not exist in translation 0.1.

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output ?

Comment: I need to get all translations 0.2 that their key not  in translation 0.1
for the example above the output will be 

{ 
    "_id" : "5c9a69ef42c82b0197a2ffb8", 
    "key" : "c",  
    "language" : "en", 
    "version" : "0.2", 
}

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to get all translations `key` that has a 0.2 version but not a 0.1 version.

- First I `$sort` the translations by versions.
- Then with `$group`, I get all the versions for a given `key`.
- `$match`remove all the key that have a version 0.1
- `$replaceRoot` keep only the last version for a `key`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "version": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$key",
      "items": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "items.version": {
        "$ne": "0.1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$last": "$items"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wg_dkM8DSg-)

---

If you remove the `$match`, you can also retrieve the last version available for each translation.

- key a => version 0.1
- key b => version 0.2
- key c => version 0.2

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "version": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$key",
      "items": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$last": "$items"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dm0cgC-OoDT)